# how to compile sass when we have nested mixins

Tags: sass, compass-sass

When I try to compile using compass, I am getting error stating that 
"Mixins may not be defined within control directives or other mixins".

Following is the code I am using

```
@mixin fn-menu {
    $triangle-height: 8px;
    $triangle-width: 16px;

    @mixin menu-marker-inner($pos: top)  {
        $size: 12px;
        $offset-height: $triangle-height;
.......
```

While googling, I found that Nested Mixins are not supported.  However this page http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html says that

```
**Smaller Improvements**

Mixins and functions may now be defined in a nested context, for example within @media rules. This also allows files containing them to be imported in such contexts.
```

I am executing the command

```
compile sass --sass-dir sass --force
```

How can I resolve this?

Unfortunately I cannot change the coding style as this code was from a product.

Comment: Upgrade your version of Sass?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare mixins and functions in `@media` rules or even inside conventional nested rules, like this:

```
.users{
  @function user-details-width($slots){
    //Some calculation here...
  }

  @mixin user-details{
    //Some syling logic here...
    width: user-details-width(3);
  }

  .details{
    @include user-details; //This is totally OK
  }
}

a{
  @include user-details; //<<<ERROR!!!
}
```

When you do this, your mixins and functions are scoped in that context (and are only visible in the same level or under).

Unfortunatelly, mixins (and functions) can't be defined inside other mixins or functions, or even control directives (`@for, @if, @while` or `@each`). The same limitation is applied to @import directives. You can do an import inside a rule, but you can't conditionate an import with an "if" directive, neither any other control directive (or mixins and functions).